Well-posedness of discretized nonlinear Schrodinger type systems
Consider the cubic NLS: $$i\dot{u} = -u_{xx} + |u|^2 u$$
When discretizations are considered, there are three famous models:

The discrete NLS which corresponds to the centered finite difference scheme for $u_{xx}$,
The Ablowitz-Ladik NLS which corresponds to changing the nonlinearity to include pair-wise coupling of the lattice sites: $|u_{n}|^2 u_{n}$ in addition to $u_{xx}$ being discretized,
The Salerno model which is a sort of combination of the above two models.

I want to understand how one shows well-posedness for either the DNLS or A-L model and am hoping users here can offer relevant resources which directly speak to the well-posedness of these models. I have examined Evan's PDE and Dispersive PDE book, but couldn't find material about this.

Any discretization that reduces the NLS to a system of ODEs automatically has local well-posedness since the RHS will be locally Lipschitz

I am unfamiliar with the type of material and would appreciate an explanation of your comment as an Answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem
